# error overriding method of class that extends generic class

Tags: java, generics

i have a class A that extends a class B and the class B extends a generic Class

my class A is:

```
public class MyCustomerReviewConverter<SOURCE extends CustomerReviewModel, TARGET extends ReviewData> extends CustomerReviewConverter{

    @Override
    public void populate(final SOURCE source, final TARGET target) {.....}
```

the extended class B is

```
public class CustomerReviewConverter extends AbstractPopulatingConverter<CustomerReviewModel, ReviewData>{

    @Override
    public void populate(final CustomerReviewModel source, final ReviewData target)
    {..........}
```

but i'm getting the error

```
 Name clash: The method populate(SOURCE, TARGET) of type MyCustomerReviewConverter<SOURCE,TARGET> has the same erasure as populate(CustomerReviewModel, ReviewData) of type 
     CustomerReviewConverter but does not override it
```

what's wrong?

As second parameter in the populate method i have to pass a class

```
MyReviewData extends ReviewData{...}
```

thanks in advance

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky and difficult to explain.

1. The type parameters are defined in the generic `AbstractPopulatingConverter`.
2. The type parameters are concretized in `CustomerReviewConverter`.
3. Then, you try to make the concretized type parameters generic again in `MyCustomerReviewConverter`.

And that just doesn't work. You're trying to override a method with a method that has a different method signature (different parameter types).

The only way you can override that method is as follows:

```
@Override
public void populate(final CustomerReviewModel source,
        final ReviewData target) { /* ... */ }
```

However, instead of **overriding** the method, you can **overload** it:

```
public void populate(final MyCustomerReviewModel source,
        final MyReviewData target) { /* ... */ }
```

If the `populate()` method is called on an object of type `MyCustomerReviewConverter` with a `MyCustomerReviewModel` and `MyReviewData` parameter, the compiler **will** select the most specific `populate` method, being the overloaded one.

Answer (score 1):

The types of the generic types for `<SOURCE, TARGET>` have already been concreted in by B as `<CustomerReviewModel, ReviewData>`.
If you want to extend B, your A should simply be:

```
public class MyCustomerReviewConverter extends CustomerReviewConverter {
    @Override
    public void populate(final CustomerReviewModel source, final ReviewData target) 
        { ... }
}
```

Otherwise you need to extend AbstractPopulatingConverter directly, and perhaps write a delegate to perform the shared logic within B so you can re-use it elsewhere.

@Robby Cornelissen explains it better than me in his answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `CustomerReviewConverter<SOURCE, TARGET>` (probably, you haven't added its definition to the question) instead of the raw type. Then you need to override `public void populate(SOURCE source, TARGET target)`.

Comment: The CustomerReviewConverter is a non generic class that extends a generic class....it's inside a library i cannot modify